# How precise does a 1:1 ratio PCR sample mixture (microliters) have to be for the liquid amount ratio to not have any effect on results

Tags: pcr, biostatistics

Amount of liquid:

5 micro liters master mix

5 micro liters of patient sample

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the site - can you please let us know what sort of PCR you are doing. Regular PCR with a gel as end-point, it might not matter too much (i.e. you just want a band), but for qPCR it will make all the difference.

Comment: If your pipets are calibrated and your technique is good, you shouldn't have issues with those volumes. Using a p10 instead of a p20 might reduce pipetting error a bit. Low-binding tips can help too, but marginally. If running reactions in duplicate or triplicate you can mix them all in one tube first, and dispense the 10 ul reactions out from that; just make them around 10% or so bigger than what you need to account for dead volume, and wet your tips before dispensing.

Answer (score 1):

Pipetting PCR reactions should be done as precise as possible - since relatively small deviations can effect the reaction. Pipetting 4 instead of 5µl results in a 10% error which for example leads to a higher magnesium concentration which may effect the reaction efficiency.

I would try to use bigger volumes (25µl is pretty common for PCR reactions) to minimize such effects, but of course smaller reactions save material and costs. You could run a few tests to see how big the effect is for different reaction volumes and if the possible error is acceptable for you.

Comment: Could you clarify more on what would be an acceptable range of deviation in that it wouldn't effect the reaction or provide me please with any reference I could view? For example if I had a total mixture of 20µl.

Comment: @Nicole you can work out the error by yourself fairly easily - it's simply your pipetting volume error divided by the expected total volume (e.g if you had a 1 ul error in expected volume 20 ul - 1/20 = 0.05 = 5%)

Comment: thank you all for the input